# Composer Uninstalling

Tags: windows, composer-php

How to remove a composer Php Dependecny Manager from system?

It says Uninstall cannot continue because the following applications are using files that need to be removed.

Windows Explorer

Comment: Close Windows Explorer (it's not Internet Explorer, but directory explorer), then repeat uninstall.

Comment: When clicking retry it says another application is using it!

Comment: Does it show the name of the application?

Comment: name is Windows Explorer

Comment: Maybe just close all applications and then execute the uninstaller.

Comment: Closed all the applications & executes the uninstaller the composer is not uninstalled

Comment: Delete it manually and report a new bug over at https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/ - or maybe its this https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/issues/39 :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and here is the solution..

- Its mainly occur due to selecting shell menu while installing.[image: composer installing]
- after selecting shell menu option you could easily access composer just right clicking [image: shell menu]
- this occur the error "cannot continue because the following applications are using files that need to be removed Windows Explorer" While uninstalling.
- for fixing this issue type  **windows key + r** and type **regedit** and **Ctrl+f for search**  and type **composer** and delete  all files related to composer.
- and remove system path to if the problem still exists

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced the problem, my solution like:

```
 1. Open the task manager 
 2. End a task called `Windows Explorer` from process tab.
 3. Retry to uninstall
```

And then I could do the uninstalling process.

Comment: thanks this helped solving this annoying issue, after closing "Windows Exploer" the task bar (on the bottom) will disappear ,to make it reappear again, press "Ctrl + Alt + Del"  and select Task manager, In Task Manager on the File menu, select New Task (Run…). Type in "explorer" and Press "OK" , this should bring back the task bar .

Answer (score 2):

For Windows on you local machine to uninstall composer, simply go to you programmer files and delete that composer setup folder if still there is files that are not getting deleted then again go to control panel and remove composer.

These steps work for me, hope will helpful for you too :)