# Reinstall composer in windows

Tags: yii, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

I tried to reinstall Composer-Setup.exe file from https://getcomposer.org/download/. But I got this error.

[image]

How can I reinstall composer?

Comment: You can remove the previous installation using control panel and disintsall  program

Comment: I already uninstall it, but I have the same error.

Comment: have you tried to restart yoyr computer ?

Comment: I have restarted, but nothing changed. Still the same error exist.

Comment: this could be useful ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496458/composer-uninstalling